# Why is this ArrayList being treated as a list of objects?

Tags: java, arraylist

Let me know if I need to provide more code, but I am getting a syntax error for the last line in this snippet stating `incompatible types; Object cannot be converted to String`. I can't figure out why this `ArrayList` is considered to be made up of `Object`s instead of `String`s.

As you can tell, `inputList` was passed down from a different method, and it gets a little complicated from here to just post snippets, but as far as I can tell, everywhere else these `ArrayList`s are always defined as `String`s.

Any input (see what I did there?) would be appreciated!

```
public static ArrayList<String> getURLsContainingTarget(ArrayList inputList, String target) throws MalformedURLException
{   
  ArrayList<String> outputList = new ArrayList<>();
  String regEx;
  regEx = "*" + target + "*"; 
  String line= "null";// this is a line in the web page
  // one loop to read through each URL in inputList 
  for (int i = 0; i < inputList.size() - 1; i++)
  {
    String URLline = inputList.get(i);
```

Comment: `ArrayList inputList` as an argument should be with `<String>` as well.

Comment: You have to define `ArrayList` of type `String`. Otherwise it ll considered as Object type, so you have to cast it.

Comment: because you have `(ArrayList inputList` instead of `(ArrayList<String> inputList`

Answer (score 4):

Your `inputList` is defined using a raw type - `ArrayList inputList` - which means, as far as the compiler is concerned, it may contain any type of Object. Therefore, `inputList.get(i)` returns `Object` and not `String`, and casting is required.

If you change your method signature to:

```
public static ArrayList<String> getURLsContainingTarget(ArrayList<String> inputList, String target) throws MalformedURLException
```

the casting won't be required.

Comment: I feel stupid now. Sometimes it really takes an extra pair of eyes. Thank you!!

Comment: Also, on a side note, work to interfaces. Use List in the signature and not ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things:

1. Make `inputList` more *strongly typed*. Use `ArrayList<String> inputList` in the function parameter list.
2. Use a *cast* at the point of use: `String URLline = (String)inputList.get(i);`

Be aware that (1) will cause *compile time* failures whereas (2) will cause *runtime* failures if `inputList` contains objects that are not `String` types. So (1) will give you more program stability but (2) will be easier to fit into your codebase, especially if you use your function `getURLsContainingTarget` in many places.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I used option 1 which works, but I didn't realize that option 2 was possible as well..

Comment: (1) is better in my opinion if you can refactor all the calls to the function.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't define type of `ArrayList` then it ll considered as Object type so you have two option :

**1 :**
define `inputList` as `String` like `ArrayList<String> inputList`

**2 :**
cast it like : 
`String URLline = (String)inputList.get(i);`

***If you don't specify a type, you're using the old non-generic version. This would basically be equivalent to:***

`ArrayList<Object> inputList= new ArrayList<Object>();`